# Django Push_notification's Bare Device can't be imported

Tags: django, django-push-notifications

I got a Django project and its model, this module imported:

```
from push_notifications.models import BareDevice
```

I have installed `push_notification` library successfully but the problem is, this library don't have any function or class named `BareDevice`

Can anyone know about this? I just stuck with this project only for this `BareDevice`

Comment: Check version of used library and if that class supposed to be there.

Comment: I am using latest library and how can i locate that version where this class exist?

Comment: Run `pip freeze` and check version.